# How to return a Stream and close the underline source?

Tags: java, stream, hbase

Here is the background. I have a operation may scan many rows from hbase. Because the number of rows may be huge, I want to return a Stream of rows. The question is : How do I close the ResultScanner?

The method like this

```
    public <T> Stream<T> getResultStream(String tableName,Scan scan, RowMapper<T> mapper){
        scan.setCaching(5000);//set number of rows to fetch for each rpc 
        Table table=this.getConnection().getTable(tableName);
        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
        return StreamSupport.stream(scanner.spliterator(),false).map(mapper::mapRow);
        // scanner.close(); where to close it ?
    }
```

Clearly I can not close ResultScanner in this method. Is there some elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way.

First we observe that `Stream` implements `AutoCloseable`.  So we can implement a Stream wrapper that closes the `scanner` instance in its `close()` method.

You could implement this by writing a Stream wrapper class by hand.  The class simply needs to delegate all `Stream` API calls to a wrapped `Stream` class.  In the case of `close()`, it also needs to close the ResultScanner resource.  You would provide that using an argument in the wrapper classes constructor.

It could look something like this:

```
public class <T> MyStreamWrapper implements Stream<T> {

    private Stream<T> stream;
    private AutoCloseable resource;

    public MyStreamWrapper(Stream<T> stream, AutoCloseable resource) {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public close() {
        this.stream.close();
        this.resource.close();
    }
       
    // methods to delegate all other Stream API methods to this.stream
}
```

(Your IDE may be able to generate a skeletal wrapper class for you to save you the effort.  Check your IDE's documentation, etc.)

You could possibly also implement this using a dynamic proxy implemented using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` ... or some other way.

Once you have implemented the wrapper class, you can wrap and return the primary stream; e.g.

```
    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
    Stream<T> stream = 
         StreamSupport.stream(scanner.spliterator(), false)
                      .map(mapper::mapRow);
    return new MyStreamWrapper<>(stream, scanner);
```

To ensure that the scanner is actually closed, the result of this method should be assigned to a resource variable in a *try with resources* statement.

But it isn't elegant.